# Logic failed on Motorola MileStone to check Phone or Tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

I am having Motorola Milestone OS 2.2.1. I am working with universal app
for phones and tablet. My logic to find Tablet or Phone is as below.

```
  WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

  float screenWidth = display.getWidth(); // Width in Pixels 480
  float screenHeight = display.getHeight();// Height in Pixels 854
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  display.getMetrics(dm);
  double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
  double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
  double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y); // Screen inches : 10.20469720465169
```

According to my logic **Tablet must be with screen size >= 6 inches**.

One Another logic is also added which considers device as tablet with screen width >= 600px

with the logic given above I am getting screen size in inches 10.20 inches while the 
same logic working fine with my all other devices..

My base SDK version is 2.3.3(11) minSDK is 3, TargetSDK is 11.

One more thing I'would like to mention here is without declaring TargetSDK 11 I'm getting Width for Samsung Tab is 400 while the actual is 600. and Im succeed with putting TargetSDK.

Suggest please. Let me know if Im wrong..